# Upload File Content via LWC to Apex

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, aura, list-view, fileupload

I am trying to build a Custom JSON to Records Import from a Record List view page.

1. On the Click of a Button or Action Link,
2. a File Upload should be displayed in a modal Lightning modal and
3. the Blob should be passed directly to an Apex method.

I tried with File Upload components, but they always require the File to be stored as a File of a Record. I want this only to be temporary.

**Is that possible or feasible? Or would you do it differently?**

*I found that, but its code and documents are so hard to decipher that I gave up after a few hours of extracting the core ideas: https://unofficialsf.com/from-josh-dayment-improved-file-upload-in-flow-screens/*

Comment: Did you try something like `<lightning-input type="file" label="Upload" onchange={handleFileUpload}></lightning-input>`? This way the blob lives only in the JS

Comment: No I did not yet try. Do you have a sample code that shows how to pass the Blob to Apex from JS?

Comment: Of course, I'm going to post it as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [`lightning-input`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/documentation) with `type="File"`:

> To retrieve the list of selected files, use `event.target.files` in the onchange event handler. Your selected files are returned in a `FileList` object, each specified as a [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) object with the `size` and `type` attributes.

This way no ContentDocument is created unless you explictly do so in an apex method.

**HTML**

```html
<lightning-input
    type="file"
    label="Upload"
    accept={acceptedFormats}
    onchange={handleUploadFile}>
</lightning-input>
```

### Text File

In the JS you could read it creating an instance of a [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) and calling [`.readAsText(File, encoding)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsText). If `encoding` parameter is not specified, it defaults to UTF-8.
When the read operation is complete it will fire a `loadend` event, so you have to define  your own function to handle it and the `result` property will contain the contents of the file as a text string.

#### CSV

**JS**

```js
acceptedFormats = ['.csv'];

handleUploadFile(event) {
    if (event.detail.files && event.detail.files.length) {
        const csvFile = event.detail.files[0];
        // you could check the file size (csvFile.size)
        
        this.showSpinner = true;
        const fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onloadend = () => {
            const fileBody = fileReader.result;
            
            const apexParams = {
                fileName: csvFile.name,
                fileBody
            };
            saveCsvFile(apexParams); // call to apex
            this.showSpinner = false; // this should be in the then() of apex call
        };
        fileReader.readAsText(csvFile);
    }
}
```

**Apex**:

```java
@AuraEnabled
public static void saveCsvFile(String fileName, String fileBody) {
    System.debug('Reading ' + fileName + ' file');
    List<String> rows = fileBody.split('\n');
    for (String row : rows) {
        System.debug('Row: ' + row);
    }
}
```

#### JSON

If you're reading a JSON, I would suggest to create an apex class to use typed deserialization.
In JS you could read it with `readAsText` then parse it to get an object and use this one as input parameter for your apex method.

**JS**

```js
acceptedFormats = ['.json'];

handleUploadFile(event) {
    if (event.detail.files && event.detail.files.length) {
        const jsonFile = event.detail.files[0];
        
        this.showSpinner = true;
        const fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onloadend = () => {
            const jsonObj = JSON.parse(fileReader.result);
            
            const apexParams = {
                fileName: jsonFile.name,
                myWrapper: jsonObj
            };
            handleJsonFile(apexParams)
                .then(() => { /* show toast or something */ })
                .catch((error) => { /* handle error */ })
                *finally(() => {
                    this.showSpinner = false;
                });
        };
        fileReader.readAsText(jsonFile);
    }
}
```

**Apex**:

```java
@AuraEnabled
public static void handleJsonFile(String fileName, MyWrapperClass myWrapper) {
    System.debug('Reading ' + fileName + ' file');
    System.debug(myWrapper);
}
```

### Binary File

If you have to read an image or a binary file and want to pass the base64 to apex, you could use [`readAsDataURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL%60):

```js
acceptedFormats = ['.jpg', '.jpeg', '.gif', '.png'];

handleUploadFile(event) {
    if (event.detail.files && event.detail.files.length) {
        const imgFile = event.detail.files[0];
        // you could check the file size (imgFile.size)
        
        this.showSpinner = true;
        
        const fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onloadend = (() => {
            const apexParams = {
                fileName: imgFile.name,
                fileType: imgFile.type
            };
            let result = fileReader.result;
            const base64 = 'base64,';
            const i = result.indexOf(base64) + base64.length;
            apexParams.base64Body = result.substring(i);
            saveImgFile(apexParams); // call to apex
            this.showSpinner = false; // this should be in the then() of apex call
        });

        fileReader.readAsDataURL(imgFile);
    }
}
```

Please note that after Base64 encoding, the size of the data is increased to ~4/3 of the original. [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#MIME):

> the final size of Base64-encoded binary data is equal to 1.37 times the original data size + 814 bytes (for headers).

Since you're passing a base64 string to apex, in order to get the blob you should call [`EncodingUtil.base64Decode(base64String)`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_restful_encodingUtil.htm#apex_System_EncodingUtil_base64Decode)

**Apex**:

```java
@AuraEnabled
public static void saveImgFile(String fileName, String fileType, String base64Body) {
    Blob fileBody = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(base64Body);
    
    ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion();
    cv.Title = fileName;
    cv.PathOnClient = fileName;
    cv.VersionData = fileBody;
    cv.IsMajorVersion = true;
    insert cv;
    
    // if you have to send it via REST Api you could use
    // request.setBodyAsBlob(fileBody);
}
```

Comment: Could you also add a bit of the Apex to show how to handle the Blob content please?

Comment: @RobertSösemann I added few examples for both text and binary files.

Comment: There are limits around the size of file you can upload via this approach, ~4.5 MB max. Due to lightning to apex restrictions.